# traefik multiport endpoint routing

Tags: docker, endpoint, traefik, swarm

I have a docker in a swarm mode and the image, that uses ports 80 for websockets and 8000 port for http.

This config makes traefik to sticky loadbalance between them, but i need different mappings - 443 TLS for http@8000 port and 80 TLS for ws@80 port.
Strictly. Probably with different LB modes on each.

Anyone can explain the way this can be achieved?
Thanx!

Initial wrong webapp container labels:

```
deploy:
  labels:
    - "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness=true"
    - "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.swarm=true"
    - "traefik.backend=webapp"
    - "traefik.docker.network=webapp-out"
    - "traefik.entrypoints=http,https"
    - "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader=true"
    - "traefik.ws.frontend.rule=Host:host.domain.local"
    - "traefik.ws.port=80"
    - "traefik.web.frontend.rule=Host:host.domain.local"
    - "traefik.web.port=8000"
    - "traefik.enable=true"
```

Comment: what does "443 TLS for http@8000 port and 80 TLS for ws@80 port" mean

Comment: This mean forward https requests from port 443 to the http port 8000
and https port 80 to the http port 80 for websockets

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `web` in

```
- "traefik.web.frontend.rule=Host:host.domain.local"
- "traefik.web.port=8000"
```

to something else, the name is used by the deprecated web provider.

Comment: I am making an educated guess based on https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/web/. And as you didn't provide any error message this is the best I can do

Comment: No error messages. Just wrong request handling logic.

Answer (score 0):

There is a backend mess with load balancer with sticks to one node.
The right way to have a different backends to serve requests from different entryPoints:

```
deploy:
  labels:
    - "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness=true"
    - "traefik.backend.loadbalancer.swarm=true"
    - "traefik.backend=no_matter"
    - "traefik.docker.network=webapp-out"
    - "traefik.entrypoints=http,https"
    - "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader=true"
    - "traefik.port=80" #No matter this section. It will be discarded.
    - "traefik.ws.frontend.rule=Host:host.domain.local"
    - "traefik.ws.backend=ws_app"
    - "traefik.ws.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness=true"
    - "traefik.ws.backend.loadbalancer.swarm=true"
    - "traefik.ws.frontend.entryPoints=http"
    - "traefik.ws.port=80"
    - "traefik.web.frontend.rule=Host:host.domain.local"
    - "traefik.web.frontend.entryPoints=https"
    - "traefik.web.backend=web_app"
    - "traefik.web.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness=true"
    - "traefik.web.backend.loadbalancer.swarm=true"
    - "traefik.web.port=8000"
    - "traefik.enable=true"
```